# How to keep my 'User-Agent headers' always up to date in my python codes?

Tags: python, python-requests, user-agent

In my research I find several ways to create a fake `User-Agent` and also hide my `User-Agent` when making requests.

But what I'm actually looking for is how do I keep my `User-Agent` always up to date without needing to get the value manually.

Manually way is search on Google for example:

[image]

Is there a correct method for this?

For example, currently the `User-Agent` I use to make requests is this:

```
import requests
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
    }

url = f'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

But the version of Chrome that is appearing is already a much older version of the one I currently use. I'd like to know if there's a way to keep this up to date without having to manually modify it every time!

Comment: Where would you get that information from exactly? Python certainly doesn't come with it. Even if you used a third-party library, you'd have to update that.

Comment: Also, that google search is just reporting what your browser submitted to it. You could get it directly from the browser yourself.

Comment: This is exactly my question @Ouroborus , because for example, if I have dozens of codes that need headers like the one in my example, would I have to manually update them all whenever any of the browsers update?

Comment: Currently, there's no way to avoid some kind of update. The least amount of updating you could do is by using a package and updating that.

Comment: This is still making me intrigued, I figured there would be some option to keep my User-Agent always up to date, but from what I understand, I'll always need to update manually, correct? Anyway, thank you so much for trying to help me @Ouroborus

Comment: User-Agent is dynamic to some degree. To get an idea of the complexity (and a possible source of "latest" UA) see [WhatIsMyBrowser](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use fake user agent:

```
https://github.com/hellysmile/fake-useragent
```

it has a lot of options and keep user agent updated.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()

ua.ie
# Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US);
ua.msie
# Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3; Trident/6.0)'
ua['Internet Explorer']
# Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)
ua.opera
# Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.11
ua.chrome
# Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'
ua.google
# Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1290.1 Safari/537.13
ua['google chrome']
# Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
ua.firefox
# Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1
ua.ff
# Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
ua.safari
# Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25

# and the best one, random via real world browser usage statistic
ua.random
```

Comment: There's also https://github.com/jnrbsn/python-latest-user-agents. However, these still require that you keep them up to date.

Comment: Good night @GabrielVieira , I tried to use this tip, but I realized that the values ​​that it delivers to Chrome are from a very old version ```Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15```, I really have doubts about being possible to update according to the current values ​​that I find on my own pc, to keep a very correct request (as if I was using the value I find if I search for my user agent on the Google site)

Comment: Try this: https://pypi.org/project/latest-user-agents/, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and after reading various examples on the internet, which partly did not work, I was able to solve this issue using the selenium module.

The following code works on Windows with Chrome as the main browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.get("chrome://version/")
user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
driver.quit()

print(f"User agent: {user_agent}")
```

I suppose this will work with any other browser like Firefox, Safari, Edge etc...

Please note, that I commented the line where you get() or call a website, you don´t need it. In the beginning, I had entered an existing website, but I didn´t want to make unnecessary external network connections, so I switched to this internal Chrome page. Then I tried the code without this line and it still works and gets you the user agent.

Answer (score -4):

You can get your browsers user agent in javascript on the console with `navigator.userAgent`. How can you automatically have this value stored into your python scripts?? I'm not really aware of a way todo that.